# Do all humans experience flatus regardless of their diet?

Tags: human-biology

Flatus frequency is affected by diet, so I was wondering if flatus production solely depends on the food eaten, meaning that some people never ever release flatus because they don't eat any flatus-producing food. I guess if they say they don't, they're probably in denial...

Comment: Have you read the book Gulp by Mary Roach ? Some interesting flatulence research and other researches regarding gut is brilliantly written !

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough food contributes the most to flatulance, it can also be caused by swallowing air when you chew gum or smoke. It can also be caused by health conditions like [coeliac disease](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeliac_disease) and [gastroenteritis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroenteritis) ([reference](http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Flatulence/Pages/Causes.aspx)). So it is indeed hard to believe when people claim that they never fart.

Answer (score 1):

Flatus is a normal product of digestion. To some extent flatus production does not depend on the types of food eaten as some of the gas is nitrogen just from air swallowed while eating. Some of the gas produced may be from bacteria in the intestinal tract. Depending on the species they may not be particularly finicky eaters, and may produce gas from any biodegradable food-item.